# why can't I set https proxy for git

Tags: git, https

When I set https proxy for git, it doesn't work:

git config --global https.proxy 'socks5://127.0.0.1:1080'

When I set http proxy for git, it works:

git config --global http.proxy 'socks5://127.0.0.1:1080'

But I was going to clone a https link:

git clone https://github.com/liuqinh2s/blog

So, why?

Answer (score 1):

[`git help config`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-httpproxy) doesn't even list any `https.*` settings. Both http- and https-related settings are configured using `http.*`

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's true. I had read some misuse of git proxy : https://gist.github.com/laispace/666dd7b27e9116faece6

Comment: @user7417422 People set a lot of wrong settings. The most often I saw is `git config user.password` which never works.